# validate csv against schema python

Tags: python, json, database, validation, csv

I want to validate csv file against a schema. 
I tried to convert the csv to json and to use [jsonschema](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) but it doesn't return the specific cells with the error as the `csvvalidator`.
So I thought to use [csvvalidator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csvvalidator) but I can't figure out how to load the schema from the DB.
 
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar needs for my stuff, therefore I purposed CSV Schema recently, see https://github.com/csv-schema/csv-schema

I am still working on the documents and more example to make it clear. But basically it allows you writing a JSON as schema to validate CSV files. It borrows lots of keywords from jsonschema, so it might be really easy for you if you have written jsonschema.

I also made a validator in Python https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycsvschema

Like what's shown in introduction, you can specify your schema like:

```
schema = {
    'fields': [
        {
            'name': 'value',
            'type': 'number',
            'multipleOf': 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Then the validator will go through the CSV file, verifying if all value under column "value" are numbers and multiple of 5.